# Pandas slicing every row item of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and in the second column there are strings. I can get the second column a number of ways:

```
df.iloc[:,1]
df.ix[:,1]
df['column_name']
```

and I can get certain rows by indexing further, `df.iloc[:,1][:4]`

But what I can't seem to do is slice every string at once in the column.
Something like `df.iloc[:,1][:][1]` returns the first row of the column but `df.iloc[:,1][1][1]` does actually give me a slice. How do I apply this to all rows of the column without a for loop?

Comment: Sorry are you after `df['column_name'].str[1]`? This will return the 2nd word in each string row

Comment: oh nice, that works !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to slice each string on each row

So

```
df['column_name'].str[1]
```

Will return the 2nd word in each row